# C# - How do I Get a users "Web Page" property from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, directory, directoryservices

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

string WebPage = "";
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    var usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, System.Environment.UserName);
    if (usr != null)
        WebPage = usr.???????????;
}
```

I am able to get things like GivenName or EmailAddress, but the Web Page property is not an option. I am just using the Web Page property to store the users Slack channel ID for direct messages and would prefer not to repurpose the VoiceTelephoneNumber property, which I can acquire and have tested as working. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any attribute that is not exposed by the `UserPrincipal` class, you can use [`GetUnderlyingObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getunderlyingobject), which returns the underlying `DirectoryEntry` object, then get the attribute from the `Properties` collection. Like this:

```
WebPage = ((DirectoryEntry) usr.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties["wWWHomePage"].Value;
```

This is one reason I don't bother with `UserPrincipal` at all. I have to resort to `DirectoryEntry` sometimes anyway. But also because of performance, which I wrote an article about: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)